# Comparing 2 Function String Results VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 separate functions, each one returns its own string value.

I am wanting to check that both return a specific string value and if they do then perform a task.

**Example:**

**If function Apples returns "Apples" and Function Pears () returns "Pears" then do something**

I am currently using 2 nested If statements and I want to know if this is the best way to do it.

```
If Apples() = "Apples" Then

        If Pears() = "Pears" Then
            "Do something here"
        End If

    End If
```

Comment: `If Apples() = "Apples" AndAlso Pears() = "Pears" Then...`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [if statements with multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25516920/if-statements-with-multiple-conditions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ANDALSO`, if the first comparison fails, the second comparison is not made:

```
If String.Compare(Apples(),"Apples", True) = 0  ANDALSO  String.Compare(Pears(),"Pears", True) = 0 Then

    'Do Something Here

    End If
```

Be careful with [string comparisons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compare?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Compare_System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_), the comparison is case sensitive.  `"Apples" <> "APPLES"`.

Another version:

```
If Apples().ToUpper = "APPLES" ANDALSO  Pears().ToUpper = "PEARS" Then
    
        'Do Something Here
    
        End If
```

Comment: Why are you making this more complicated than it has to be (using `String.Compare()`)? What's wrong with checking  if `Apples() = "Apples"`?

Comment: @ Ahmed Abdelhameed: Case sensitivity.  The other way would be to wrap UPPER or lower to prevent case sensitive comparison.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice you passed `True` for the `ignoreCase` parameter. Okay, fair point. I still wouldn't use `.Compare` if I wanted the comparison to be case-insensitive. `Applies().Equals("Apples", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` is better, IMO.

Comment: @ Ahmed Abdelhameed: Not know what the functions are supposed to do, instead of returning a string, have the function return a boolean.  Then it becomes really easy to compare.  <code>    If Apples() andalso Pears() Then

Comment: @ Ahmed Abdelhameed: we have a lot of options for string comparison.  One issue is, if a NULL/Nothing returned, handling that correctly.